# Using Octave in C++

Tags: c++, octave

I am new in both Octave and C++ ! I want to use Octave in C++ and found this [webpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs). I started with the upper code and tried to run it. Unfortunately there is no document on this matter and I encountered with a lot of errors. I first used msvc 2010 and found that the I should use gcc!! Here are what I'v done so far:

1. Download Octave from this [link](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/), (I download octave-4.0.0_0.zip)
2. I tried to compile this code:

   ```
   int main (void)
   {
     std::cout << "Hello Octave world!\n";

     int n = 2;
     Matrix a_matrix = Matrix (n, n);

     for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
       for (octave_idx_type j = 0; j < n; j++)
         a_matrix(i,j) = (i + 1) * 10 + (j + 1);

     std::cout << a_matrix;

     return 0;
   }
   ```

I also included: 1) iostream and 2) octave directory: N:\octave-4.0.0\include\octave-4.0.0\octave\oct.h

I got this error in msvc10:
1>n:\octave-4.0.0\include\math.h(169): error C2065: '**asm**' : undeclared identifier
1>n:\octave-4.0.0\include\math.h(169): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '**volatile**'
1>n:\octave-4.0.0\include\math.h(169): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ':'
1>n:\octave-4.0.0\include\math.h(169): error C2059: syntax error : ')'

and this error in codeblocks using gcc:

> C:/Users/Sam/Documents/codeblock_C++/testOctave/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Matrix const&)'
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function`ZN10dim_vector11make_uniqueEv':
>   N:/octave-4.0.0/include/octave-4.0.0/octave/dim-vector.h:134: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function`ZN10dim_vectorD1Ev':
>   N:/octave-4.0.0/include/octave-4.0.0/octave/dim-vector.h:286: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function`ZN15octave_refcountIiEmmEv':
>   N:/octave-4.0.0/include/octave-4.0.0/octave/oct-refcount.h:72: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function`ZN5ArrayIdEC2ERK10dim_vector':
>   N:/octave-4.0.0/include/octave-4.0.0/octave/Array.h:184: undefined reference to `dim_vector::safe_numel() const'
>   obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6Matrix[__ZTV6Matrix]+0x10): undefined reference to`Array::resize_fill_value() const'
>   obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV7NDArray[__ZTV7NDArray]+0x10): undefined reference to `Array<double>::resize_fill_value() const'
>   obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6MArrayIdE[__ZTV6MArrayIdE]+0x10): undefined reference to`Array::resize_fill_value() const'
>   obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV5ArrayIdE[__ZTV5ArrayIdE]+0x10): undefined reference to `Array::resize_fill_value() const'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: If you could, how about try it on Linux first?

Comment: I also have Ubuntu, do you know how I can do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to start by compiling Octave itself on Ubuntu. You can refer to [this](https://scivision.co/compiling-octave-3-8/) or [this](https://scivision.co/compiling-octave-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/). Then follow the instructions on the Octave web page you found.

Comment: I know its year old thread but I am also getting same error while compiling with visual studio 2013.Anyone have any leads?

Comment: I've tried compiling with MinGW and Cygwin - still errors 'undefined reference to...' in area of dim_vector and Array. Anyone got a clue on this?

Comment: you are using mkoctfile to compile the program?

Comment: I have worked example, see this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995515/octave-qt-libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995515/octave-qt-libsvm)

Answer (score 1):

Octave > 4.0 is using msys and gcc in thein windows, but you don't really need to know that in order to get it to compile.

Looking at what you are trying to do, your are using a IDE other than octave to try to compile the code without then including the octave paths and octave libraries correctly.

The easiest way is to use octave to do it.

Firstly you will need to include the octave header, and since you are using cout, iostream:

```
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Then from octave us the mkoctfile command with the --link-stand-alone option as shown in the link you referenced.

```
mkoctfile --link-stand-alone main.cpp
```